# Purpose of PHP code in jQuery plugin?

Tags: php, jquery

I am looking at this jQuery plugin for embedding a Twitter feed:

https://github.com/sonnyt/Tweetie/blob/master/index.html

It requires the user to set authentication in a .php file and has other .php files in the source.

I was thrown off by this because I thought jQuery was a client-side library.

I am unsure if I am missing something about how to use it, or if it has a server-side component to it's implementation.

How is this meant to be used client-side? Is the /api/ folder that contains the php files meant to be used on the server somehow?

Any help understanding this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what the codes looks like, yes the api should in the server.

And as you can see in the plugin Options, you can specify the API url (apiPath), which is the server side script on your server.

See this file: 
https://github.com/sonnyt/Tweetie/blob/master/tweetie.js

You can see on line 98, the script basically just make ajax (getJson jquery) call to your server side API script.

From my brief understanding, what this plugin do is, it help you to fetch and process the Twitter API for you, and allow you to customize the output more by setting the options. So that's why the plugin must have a server side script.

Comment: I see. perhaps I can modify it's GET request to use the response from a node twitter client since I don't have experience with php. I see there are also official twitter javascript widgets out there. Thanks.

Comment: To add up, You cannot make ajax call on other domains (unless this has changed in the past few months). So you need to make the call to your own domain. Then your server make the call to the twitter api and return the data to the client so it can be dynamicaly added to the page.

Comment: Yes, so If I was to use this library, I guess I would make an express route to get the twitter feed on the same server that hosts the webpage.